# three20 application crash in class TTBaseViewController.m : UIViewControllerGarbageCollection.h' file not found

Tags: ios4, xcode4, three20

I am using Xcode4 and try to implement the three30 framework in my app
Source : http://galic-design.com/objective-c/make-my-own-iphone-app-looking-like-facebook-app#comment-27

my application crashes before launching
It crashes in class **TTBaseViewController.m**
in function

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

at line

```
UIViewController* popup = [self popupViewController];
```

**[Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"]**

Any Idea what is the issue

Also its giving error in same class
*file://localhost/Users/amit/works/three20/src/Three20UICommon/Sources/TTBaseViewController.m: error: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'Three20UICommon/private/UIViewControllerGarbageCollection.h' file not found*